# How do I use my Stripe button with a true/false check?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe as my payment processor, and have implemented a custom button. However, I realized that I also need to check if the user has entered shipping info before I allow them to pay (I realize that I could just have it on a separate page, but I'd prefer if they didn't have to jump to a new page).

However, when I attempted to add an IF to the Stripe form, I ran into issues. Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K843E/1/

```
<form method="post" action="stripeprocess.php" id="cartform2">
<button id="customButton2" type="button">With Check</button>
<script>
    var check = false;
    if(check) {
    $('#customButton2').click(

    function() {

        var token = function(res) {
            var $input = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
            $('#cartform2').append($input).submit();
        };

        StripeCheckout.open({

            address: true,
            amount: 1000,
            currency: 'usd',
            name: 'Test',
            description: 'Item Description',
            panelLabel: 'Checkout',

            token: token
        }
    }
    );

        return false;
    });
```

The top button shows how it should work if the IF statement returns true, the bottom button is my attempt at the IF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of syntax error in that code i fixed it here, now it works with true or false on check.

```
 var check = false;
        if(check) {
        $('#customButton2').click(

        function() {

            var token = function(res) {
                var $input = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
                $('#cartform2').append($input).submit();
            };

            StripeCheckout.open({

                address: true,
                amount: 1000,
                currency: 'usd',
                name: 'Test',
                description: 'Item Description',
                panelLabel: 'Checkout',

                token: token
            } );



            return false;
        });
        }
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K843E/2/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think you understood me. The first button always worked. The second button doesn't work on your Working DEMO, and that's the one that needs work.

Comment: That seems to fix it. Thanks!